# Pattern for Current Date Problem in Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns

Is there a common knowledge pattern or idiom to solve the problem that code that uses new Date() is extremely hard to unit-test?

I know a possible solution (e.g. http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.com/2010/02/unit-testing-code-which-is-dependent-on.html), but the question is whether there is a common pattern and language for this problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454106/how-can-i-mock-jodatime-actual-date

Comment: Thanks. But this is just another solution. I am looking for a pattern and thus common language, but it seems that everbody is doing it in its own way. Even tough the solution is simple, a pattern/idiom would help in communication.

Answer (score 2):

What I sometimes do is build an Interface that is responsible for returning the date.
for example:

```
public interface ISystemClock
{
    DateTime GetCurrentDate();
}
```

this could then be mocked out if required for unit tests.

Comment: I try this, but I have some issue with it. Here is my post, can u take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049777/mockito-how-to-mock-an-interface-of-jodatime

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to simply move anything that is difficult to test (i.e. difficult to control for the purposes of unit testing) behind an interface. Follow that up with a Fake or a Mock which gives you the required control.

The blogpost that you linked in the question is right for the most part.. However I personally wouldn't do the last bit of creating a TestableClock which instantiates the dependency. I'd prefer to pass it in as a ctor argument or a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't understood wrongly your needs, you're looking for "mocking":

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

That's providing a fake implementation for some underlying code that's not part of the test, but it must work properly in order to successfully test some logic.

Comment: In Java it is not so trivial, and probably not so good practice to mock Calendar.getInstance()

Comment: Well in .NET we've a good project called "Moles" which create a mocked version of any class in any assembly (I believe that "assembly" for Java is "jar"), so it becomes trivial. For example, if you've DateTime.Now, Moles creates a MDateTime.Now "Mocked DateTime", and you can change what "NoW" does by setting in it a lambda expression. Maybe Java has something like Moles?

Answer (score 0):

That is it. You'll have to mock/fake the reading of the time. This can extend beyond just the system time. You could have a general "environment" interface that allows you to gain control over other non-deterministic factors for your testing.