# How to ban moreunit for executing automatically the tests?

Tags: eclipse, junit, mockito

I install "MoreUnit" as a plugin in eclipse. but, when starting eclipse, tests will be launched automatically. This presents a problem for me, because the tests inclurent of the heads of CRUD. Therefore, because of this automatic startup, the database will be empty after a certain time.

How to ban moreunit  for executing automatically the tests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MoreUnit is a tool to assist in unit testing. If your tests are doing anything with a database, they are not unit tests. The reason for this is that if you test your class with a real database connection, you are also testing the database along with your class.

You should decouple your dependency on the database with a mock (see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049777/mockito-how-to-mock-an-interface-of-jodatime/6060814#6060814) for an idea how to do this).

If you are doing data-driven tests, then it would be better to use a tool such as [DbUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) to drive your tests rather than relying on a real database connection. With such a tool, you will have control over the data for each test and won't have to worry that tests fail because someone else updated data in the database or that you executed your tests in "the wrong order".